# ToCharArray generates two sets of numbers instead of one

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to split a string into  an array of chars but for some reason the result is not what I expect.I passed this piece of code threw with the debugger and i gave it the string "34325".When I reach the part of the code that converts the string into an array of chars for some reason I can see two sets of chars in the debugger.I get something like this:

char[0] = 51 '3'
char[1] = 52 '4'
char[2] = 51 '3'
char[3] = 50 '2'
char[4] = 53 '5'

When I then convert each element of the char array into an int the first number of is always take : 51 , 52 ,51 , 50 , 53.

My question is how can I correct this so I get 3 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 5?
And also from where are this numbers coming from when I use the toCharArray() method : 51 ,52 ,51 ,50 53?

This is my code:

```
    value = TextBox1.Text;

    char[] numberChars = value.ToCharArray();
    int[] numbers = numberChars.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++ ) {
        TextBox2.Text += numbers[i] + " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to split the string into integer numbers representing the digits, as follows: `"34325"` becomes `new int[] {3,4,3,2,5}`.

Change your code as follows to interpret each character that represents a digit as a single-digit number:

```
 int[] numbers = numberChars.Select(x => ((int)x)-'0').ToArray();
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/HHQLnl).

The reason you see numbers `51`, `52`, and so on is that you see ASCII codes for the corresponding digits.

Comment: ok I tested this and it works but I do not understand this expresion ((int)x) - '0'.I understand that (int)x casts the element to an integer but what does - '0' do?

Comment: Since '0' is ASCII 48, by subtracting the CHARACTER 0 from the numbers, you'll get the number value it represents instead of the ASCII value.

Comment: @NistorAlexandru The constant `'0'` represents the ASCII code of the digit zero. Since all decimal digits occupy consecutive spots in ASCII and in UNICODE, subtracting the code of zero from the code of another character representing a digit gives you the distance from that digit to zero, which is also the integer value of that digit.

Answer (score 2):

the "other" sequence you got is the sequence of ascii values ...

have a look at `int.Parse(string)`